# "Найкон" или "Никон"?

Tags: заимствования, фонетика

И еще по фотоаппаратам. Я никак не могу определиться, как правильно произносить марку фотоаппаратов Nikon. По идее, это открытый слог, и английское i читается как "ай" по аналогии с "найк". Но большинство говорит "Никон". Хотя, с другой стороны, "мадэ ин чина" тоже говорят. А как все-таки правильно говорить? А то, общаясь с фотографами, не хочется попасть впросак.

Comment: А еще интереснее, что в слове закрытый слог, и по правилам английского тоже читается как «никон». Поэтому, наверное, и британцы произносят именно так. Американцы переиначили.

Comment: Де-юре это открытый слог. Хотя всё равно может читаться по правилу закрытого, но здесь для этого причин нет. Так что это скорее всего просто особенность проищношения личного имени.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компания японская, а японцы произносят нИкон, послушать можно, например [здесь](http://ru.forvo.com/word/nikon/). По-русски тоже устоялось именно нИкон.

Кстати, с Nike тоже всё не так просто. Компания названа в честь богини Ники (логотип - это её крыло) и в оригинале название фирмы произносят как "нАйки". Однако в России прижилось именно название Найк.

Comment: А откуда второе И "в оригинале"?

Answer (score 5):

Nikon - фирма японская, читается "Никон". "Найкон" - это уже английское прочтение. Но возникает новый вопрос: НИкон или НикОн? В Википедии дается ударение на второй слог. Но когда-то на слуху была реклама со слоганом: Nikon - ideas for life. Там звучало "НИкон". Знакомые, работающие с этой фирмой, говорят: "НИкон".

Comment: Попробовала японскую озвучку. Nikon звучит [н'и:кон'] с очень долгой "и", менее долгой, но четкой "о" и мягкой "н" в конце :)

Comment: А как иероглифами будет записано это название?

Comment: ニコン - если вам это чем-то поможет :)

Comment: Интересно, а слог "ниии" - это, в смысле "брат"? Хотя, записано катаканой, а так они обычно пишут слова иностранного происхождения.

Comment: Огромное всем спасибо!

Comment: > "Найкон" - это уже английское прочтение.

А точнее, **американское**. Британцы предпочитают говорить "нИкон". А в США существует произношение "нАйкон". [Источник][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon

Comment: По поводу не английского, а американского прочтения - согласна. Моя неточность.

Comment: По поводу японского написания,  в Википедии ニコン. http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon

Comment: ニコン- это не иероглифы, катакана