# Произношение

Tags: заимствования, фонетика

Здравствуйте.

Один известный блоггер, дизайнер и сын не менее известной писательницы написал:

Запомните:

не Найкон, а Никон

Не Эдоуби, а Адобе

не Майкрософт (с ударением на а), а Микрософт (с
ударением на о)

Не Виллерой и Бох, а Виллеруа и Бох

Кто не согласен, тому майкроскоуп в одно место".

Как вы считаете, он прав?

Ведь имя и название не одно и то же.
Мы же не произносим Peter как Петер,а говорим Питер и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насчет Никона сразу скажу: блоггер прав. Слово японское и произносить его все-таки следует по японским правилам, то есть, именно "никон" (ударение - без разницы, в японском оно не фиксированное). Что до Adobe, то, если уж передавать звучание английского слова (что в переводе означает кирпич-саман), то будет "Эдоуб" (и уж Е на конце точно читаться не будет), а вот с Майкрософтом он что-то загнул. С какого перепугу ударение должно падать на О? В английском языке ударение почти всегда падает на первый слог.
Так что, далеко не во всем прав сынок писательницы.

Answer (score 2):

Никон уже обсуждался [ССЫЛКА](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17827/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD)

**Adobe** произносят по разному, но к английскому варианту будет ближе [Эдоуби](http://ru.forvo.com/word/adobe/#en)

**Microsoft** в английском произносится мАйкрософт Есть дочерняя компания "Майкрософт Рус", так что не "микрософт" точно. А вот насчёт ударения я бы согласился с Артемием Лебедевым, ударение на первый слог в русском языке неэстетично, на втором слоге оно смотрелось бы уместнее, так как в этом случае редукция гласных не мешает восприятию. Хотя от меня тут мало зависит.

Про "**Виллеруа и Бох**" всё верно. Именна эта транслитерация дана на официальном сайте компании [ССЫЛКА](http://www.hogart-art.ru/villeroyboch_about_site/)

Answer (score 1):

Забавно. А кто устанавливает нормы произношения иностранных слов? Англо-американцы? Почему мы тогда не говорим *Инглия* вместо *Англия*? Почему не требуем от них говорить *Руссия* вместо *Раша*?

Comment: После Олимпийских игр они вообще будут звать нас презрительно "Рашка". Надо ускорить развитие наших вооружённых сил, иного пути заставить уважать себя нет. Только б не надорваться, как было с СССР!